# need to find a way for polyp detection in a 2D image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am currently learning OpenCV. I am using OpenCV to perform segmentation and object detection in 2D images. I need to find a way to detect polyps in the intestines.Refer the pic below:-

[image]

I used object detection but that would need a template and one the disadvantages is that the template wont be rotated or scaled to check whether there are any similar copies in the source image. So i'm trying to find a new way to detect these polyps.I would be grateful if anyone of you could help me with this.

Comment: Are there three polyps in the above picture, or just one?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the polyps appear on the outline of the black holes.

A first step will be to find the holes by blob analysis and perform outline following.

Then, construct the intrinsic representation of the outline curves, i.e. the signed curvature as a function of the curvilinear abscissa. (You will compute numerical approximations of the latter.)

For sure, the polyps will exhibit a specific and discriminant signature on this representation.